Kotlin notification manager and canvas draw updates stop
I have a foreground service that works as a countdown timer for the upcoming prayer. I use canvas draw to add customized typeface.
My problem is after about two minutes, the notification manager stops updating the imageview with the corresponding time.
Here is my code:
fun createBitmapFromText(context:Context,messageText:String,textSize:Float,textColor:Int):Bitmap {
        val fontName = "cairo_medium_500"
        val font = Typeface.createFromAsset(
            context.assets,
            String.format("%s.ttf", fontName)
        )

        val paint = Paint()
        paint.textSize = textSize
        paint.setTypeface(font)
        paint.color = textColor
        paint.textAlign = Paint.Align.LEFT
        
        val baseline = -paint.ascent() // ascent() is negative
        val width = (paint.measureText(messageText) + 0.5f).toInt() // round
        val height = (baseline + paint.descent() + 0.5f).toInt()
        val image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

        val canvas = Canvas(image)
        canvas.drawText(messageText, 0f, baseline, paint)

        return image
    }

and here's the code used in the service class for the countdown and update:
 private fun startLiveNextPrayerTimer(futureMillisTime: Long, context: Context) {

    countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(futureMillisTime, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            Log.e("onTick", secondsToHHmmss(millisUntilFinished / 1000))
            contentView.setImageViewBitmap(
                R.id.tvCounter,
                createBitmapFromText(context, secondsToHHmmss(millisUntilFinished / 1000), 40.0f, Color.GRAY)

            )
            notificationManager.notify(1, notification);

        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            setPrayerNotificationCounter()
        }

    }

    countDownTimer.start()

}

Could someone tell me what I am soing wrong, please?

What type of foreground service did you declare? Because a short service can only run up to three minutes. Reference

First, I didn't specify any type, and now I used specialUse type but the problem remains existent
